# Understanding Autofac configuration for Mediatr

Tags: c#, autofac, mediatr

I'm trying to configure [Mediatr](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) with Autofac. The [documentation](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#autofacs) shows how to configure it, but I don't understand how the ServiceFactory registration works.

The registration is as follows:

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(ctx =>
{
   var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
   return t => c.Resolve(t);
});
```

And ServiceFactory is a delegate:

```
/// <summary>
/// Factory method used to resolve all services. For multiple instances, it will resolve against <see cref="IEnumerable{T}" />
/// </summary>
/// <param name="serviceType">Type of service to resolve</param>
/// <returns>An instance of type <paramref name="serviceType" /></returns>
public delegate object ServiceFactory(Type serviceType);
```

My understanding is that when resolving `ServiceFactory`, Autofac will resolve the anonymous function:

```
 t=>c.Resolve(t)
```

but I don't understand why `IComponentContext` is resolved from `ctx`, given that ctx is already an `IComponentContext`.

So what difference would it make to register it this way:

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(ctx =>
{
   return t => ctx.Resolve(t);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that when resolving ServiceFactory, Autofac will resolve the anonymous function

You are right.

> but I don't understand why `IComponentContext` is resolved from `ctx`, given that `ctx` is already an `IComponentContext`.

You can't use `ctx` because this context will be disposed when the delegate will be invoked. If you do

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(ctx =>
{
    return t => ctx.Resolve(t);
});
```

You will have a `ObjectDisposedException` when you invoke the `ServiceFactory` delegate.

> `System.ObjectDisposedException`: This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components using lambdas, the `IComponentContext` 'ctx' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. Instead, either resolve `IComponentContext` again from 'ctx', or resolve a `Func<>` based factory to create subsequent components from.

the `ctx` provided by the `Register` method is built only for the registration process and will be disposed at the end of it. That's why you have to resolve another `IComponentContext` to get one which will be alive the whole lifetime scope.

Comment: This makes total sense. I didn't experience the ObjectDisposedException in my tests, but I only did simple debugging sessions which probably don't reflect the real working conditions. Thanks.